# Bootstrap's close button doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display an alert message with a close button with Twitter Bootstrap. But it doesn't work with Chrome. So I created a jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6vD5j/3/, but strangely this jsFiddle doesn't work.

```
<div class='alert alert-error'>
    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button>
    Test
</div>
```

So I'm lost, and I require your help please.

**[EDIT]** If I run this locally on Chrome, it doesn't work :

```
<?php echo "<link href='http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen'>

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

<div class='alert alert-error'>
<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>x</button>
Test
</div>";
?>
```

Comment: Did you load bootstrap.js?

Comment: Yes, like in my Jsfiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something was wrong with your bootstrap.js. I uploaded it again and now it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/6vD5j/4/

You used 2.0.2, and I changed it to 2.3.1 which is the current version. My guess is that this functionality wasn't available in 2.0.2.

The HTML is the same:

```
<br><br>
<div class='alert alert-error'>
<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button>
Test
</div>
```

Comment: Does the order of calls (bootstrap.js, jquery.js...) has an importance ?

Comment: Yes, jquery.js must come first because bootstrap.js depends on it.

Comment: The Jsfiddle works, thank you, but locally it doesn't work... I've edited my question, could you see it please ?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? (Ctrl+Shift+I)

Comment: Ok, I'm totally stupid... I've blocked Javascript in Chrome. Sorry.